# Find the binomial expansion $(k+x)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i) Find in terms of the non zero constant $k$, the first four terms on the expansion $(k+x)^n$ in ascending powers of $x$

ii) Given that the cooefficients of the $x^2$ and $x^{3}$ are equal, find the value of $k$.

I really neeed help on these so any help is highly appreciated!

No clue how to start. :(

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Do you really mean $x^{-3}$, or do you mean $x^3$? Because there is no term $x^{-3}$ in the expansion.

Comment: Oh sorry, your right it's x^3

Answer (score 2):

HINT: At this point you’re expected to know the binomial expansion:

$$(k+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}ik^{n-i}x^i\;.$$

The first four terms are the terms for $i=0,1,2,3$:

$$\binom{n}0k^n,\quad\binom{n}1k^{n-1}x,\quad\binom{n}2k^{n-2}x^2,\quad\text{and}\quad\binom{n}3k^{n-3}x^3\;.$$

Since the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^3$ are equal, you know that

$$\binom{n}2k^{n-2}=\binom{n}3k^{n-3}\;.$$

Divide out the common factors and expand the binomial coefficients into fairly simple fractions, and you’ll be able to solve for $k$ as a fairly simple function of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).